# How can I easily maintain a cross-file JavaScript Library Development Environment

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I have been developing a new JavaScript application which is rapidly growing in size.

My entire JavaScript Application has been encapsulated inside a single function, in a single file, in a way like this:

```
(function(){  
   var uniqueApplication = window.uniqueApplication = function(opts){
      if (opts.featureOne)
      {
         this.featureOne = new featureOne(opts.featureOne);
      }
      if (opts.featureTwo)
      {
         this.featureTwo = new featureTwo(opts.featureTwo);
      }
      if (opts.featureThree)
      {
         this.featureThree = new featureThree(opts.featureThree);
      }
   };

   var featureOne = function(options)
   {
       this.options = options;
   };
   featureOne.prototype.myFeatureBehavior = function()
   {
       //Lots of Behaviors
   };

   var featureTwo = function(options)
   {
       this.options = options;
   };
   featureTwo.prototype.myFeatureBehavior = function()
   {
       //Lots of Behaviors
   };

   var featureThree = function(options)
   {
       this.options = options;
   };
   featureThree.prototype.myFeatureBehavior = function()
   {
       //Lots of Behaviors
   };
})();
```

In the same file after the anonymous function and execution I do something like this:

```
(function(){
   var instanceOfApplication = new uniqueApplication({
       featureOne:"dataSource",
       featureTwo:"drawingCanvas",
       featureThree:3540
   });
 })();
```

Before uploading this software online I pass my JavaScript file, and all it's dependencies, into Google Closure Compiler, using just the default Compression, and then I have one nice JavaScript file ready to go online for production.

This technique has worked marvelously for me - as it has created only one global footprint in the DOM and has given me a very flexible framework to grow each additional feature of the application.  However - I am reaching the point where I'd really rather not keep this entire application inside one JavaScript file.

I'd like to move from having one large uniqueApplication.js file during development to having a separate file for each feature in the application, featureOne.js - featureTwo.js - featureThree.js

Once I have completed offline development testing, I would then like to use something, perhaps Google Closure Compiler, to combine all of these files together - however I want these files to all be compiled inside of that scope, as they are when I have them inside one file - and I would like for them to remain in the same scope during offline testing too.

I see that Google Closure Compiler supports an argument for passing in modules but I haven't really been able to find a whole lot of information on doing something like this.

Anybody have any idea how this could be accomplished - or any suggestions on a development practice for writing a single JavaScript Library across multiple files that still only leaves one footprint on the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [jQuery github](http://github.com/jquery/jquery) has a similar setup to the one you speak of.  There is even a [`Makefile`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/Makefile) / [ant `build.xml`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/build.xml) that use the google closure complier.

The basic concept is to develop all your stuff in separate files, then use `cat` (or something similar) to put all the files together.

```
 cat intro.js core.js featureOne.js featureTwo.js featureThree.js outro.js > build/script.js
```

The code inside `intro.js` and `outro.js` from jQuery:

```
 // intro.js
 (function(window, undefined) {

 // outro.js
 })(window);
```

Comment: AH man thank you so much - great links on John Resig's Makefile/ANT Build.XML - but as soon as you explained the basic concept I had exactly what I need.

Comment: I'm leaving the office now, so I won't get to really do this until tomorrow, but using this advice I'm going to do the following:

((I have a Windows BATCH File that is using the Google Closure Compiler))

Command to CAT in Windows XP: 
type intro.js core.js featureOne.js featureTwo.js outro.js > combined.js

Pass the results to Google Closure Compiler and enable a source map so I can debug line by line locally still.
java -jar compiler.jar --js combined.js --create_source_map ./sourceMap --js_output_file productionCode.js

This is perfect, ah thank you again I am so happy!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at how this library is built
http://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM

The files are separated, but merged together, placed into a closure, and run through [jslint](http://jslint.com) by the ant script (build.xml).

The ant script also does conditional 'compilation', string replacements and minification.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you split your code base into AMD/RequireJS-style modules.

The AMD format seems to meet most of your requirements, and is rapidly becoming a de facto standard.