# How to create makefile to compile JavaScripts?

Tags: javascript, makefile, minify, qunit

How can I (and what tools do I need to) create a makefile that:

- Combine all JavaScripts '/js/*.js' (in a manual order - possibly with cat)
- Verify that combined script works against unit tests (which using qUnit)
- Minify JavaScripts
- Verify that minified script works against same unit tests

I would like makefile to work on Mac OS command line.

I will be uploading the Makefile to a GitHub repository, so I would like something that other developers will be able to use easily.

Comment: This'll probably need several tools to run the unittests and to minify the script. Also, the order on the js-files would need to be set explicitly somewhere (and hopefully not in the make-file). They should probably be named in order (something like `01-jquery.js`, `02-myfile.js` and such).

Comment: A makefile is just a text file, you can "create" it with any text editor-- you just have to know what you're doing. Have you gotten a "hello world" makefile to work? And do you know how to do those four things by hand?

Comment: @Beta I am able to write basic makefiles (with custom command line options, etc) I just literally do not know how to do the four things by hand, and what features other developers are likely to require from the makefile

Comment: You've got to figure out how to do these things by hand on the command line first-- there's just no way around this. For the first one, you could try `cat js/*.js > destination` and see if that's what you want.

Comment: See this other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916980/how-can-i-easily-maintain-a-cross-file-javascript-library-development-environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the suggestions, here is the solution that I have decided to go with:

- Makefiles - just as a shortcut really
- Google V8 - to execute JavaScript from command-line

I can easily perform minification and unit testing using JavaScript.

I have made a few minor changes (added ability to write files) to the sample shell application that comes with V8 and compiled on OS X. I plan to somehow cross-compile for OS X and Windows in both 32bit and 64-bit. I will include binaries for V8 and custom application source in the GitHub repository. I will include instructions to obtain and compile V8 for those who want to customise or recompile.

V8 will be doing all of the work (essentially). Whilst I have yet to bring all of these things together, I believe that this *should* work.

The only downside is that DOM based unit testing cannot be automated. It might be possible to get the DOM stuff from the Chromium project, but this is probably going to be too time consuming. I'll leave that to an enthusiastic contributor (should anybody want to).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one complex script you could look for inspiration:

https://github.com/mobilizejs/mobilize.js/blob/master/release.py

(check also README)

Generally there are always project specific use cases and one solution does not fit every project, thus everyone is doing ad hoc scripts. Also, makefile is pretty limited in the end - I recommed to pick a real scripting tool.

Comment: I don't mind using Python (or any other scripting language) provided that it is available on Mac OS without installation. I want to make it as easy as possible. I know how to do these things using a web browser (for qunit) and PHP, but I am having a tough time working out this "glue" bit. jQuery seems to be using all sorts of complex stuff in its MakeFile...looks like it even executes JavaScript directly. I would like to know how to do something similar but am lost...

Comment: Osx comes with Python (there is no Mac OS). To run browser tests from commandline, use something like JsTestDriver or Selenium.

Comment: Some JsTestDriver samples + readme. https://github.com/miohtama/Krusovice JsTestDriver supports QUnit and JsUnit.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa: There is no "Osx" either - it's "OS X" although earlier version were "MacOS X" ;)